# C# - remove blocks of bytes in large binary files

Tags: c#, filestream

i want a fast way in c# to remove a blocks of bytes in different places from binary file of size between 500MB to 1GB , the start and the length of bytes needed to be removed are in saved array

```
int[] rdiDataOffset= {511,15423,21047};
int[] rdiDataSize={102400,7168,512};
```

***EDIT:***
this is a piece of my code and it will not work correctly unless i put buffer size to 1:

```
while(true){
    if (rdiDataOffset.Contains((int)fsr.Position))
    {
        int idxval = Array.IndexOf(rdiDataOffset, (int)fsr.Position, 0, rdiDataOffset.Length);
        int oldRFSRPosition = (int)fsr.Position;
        size = rdiDataSize[idxval];
        fsr.Seek(size, SeekOrigin.Current);

    }
    int bufferSize = size == 0 ? 2048 : size;
    if ((size>0) && (bufferSize > (size))) bufferSize = (size);
    if (bufferSize > (fsr.Length - fsr.Position)) bufferSize = (int)(fsr.Length - fsr.Position);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int nofbytes = fsr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fsr.Flush();
    if (nofbytes < 1)
    {
     break;
    }
   }
```

Comment: So not "pieces of bytes", blocks of bytes? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: And I want a fast way to detect questions whose authors want us to do their work for them. Looks like we'll both be disappointed.

Comment: im not looking for some one to do my work , i asked here cuz i have tried alot , and i have spent three days thinking of this and i cant get a way that at least work correct and yes i want to remove some blocks of binary

Comment: You need to keep in mind also that when you remove a block of bytes, the positions of all the following bytes are altered. eg - I remove bytes positions 500 to 1000, now the byte that was originally in position 1001 is at position 500. This may effect subsequent block removes (causing the wrong set of bytes to be removed if you don't adjust your subsequent block parameters after each move).

Comment: yes i knew that and i have takecared of that problem just still the remove operation

Comment: plz see the edit of my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple algorithm for doing this using a temp file (it could be done in-place as well but you have a riskier situation in case things go wrong).

1. Create a new file and call [SetLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1bayf94(v=vs.110).aspx) to set the stream size (if this is too slow you can Interop to [SetFileValidData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365544(v=vs.85).aspx)).  This ensures that you have room for your temp file while you are doing the copy.
2. Sort your removal list in ascending order.
3. Read from the current location (starting at 0) to the first removal point.  The source file should be opened without granting Write share permissions (you don't want someone mucking with it while you are editing it).
4. Write that content to the new file (you will likely need to do this in chunks).
5. Skip over the data not being copied
6. Repeat from #3 until done
7. You now have two files - the old one and the new one ... replace as necessary.  If this is really critical data you might want to look a transactional approach (either one you implement or using something like NTFS transactions).
8. Consider a new design.  If this is something you need to do frequently then it might make more sense to have an index in the file (or near the file) which contains a list of inactive blocks - then when necessary you can compress the file by actually removing blocks ... or maybe this IS that process.

Comment: thats a good strategy and i think its exaclty like what im working on except the problem with my code is that the buffer is set to 1 ,also i haven't understand this function and why to use it SetFileValidData

Comment: The purpose of SetLength or SetFileValidData is to set the length of the temporary file to the required length before writing data.

Comment: if i have read with buffer of size 2048 how could i skip dat ?

Comment: I haven't tested this - at all.  Not even once.  But I'd probably try something more like this:  https://gist.github.com/bubbafat/a66da6f34831956d907d

Answer (score 4):

No common file system provides an efficient way to remove chunks from the middle of an existing file (only truncate from the end). You'll have to copy all the data after the removal back to the appropriate new location.

Comment: could you please provide me an example, if you could provide example with filestream using buffer it would be nice

Comment: It should be trivial: read from old location, write to new location. There may even be a helper method in FileStream to do it.

Comment: i have tried with filestream using seek but i can't imagine any way to it with right way except if i set the buffer size to 1 , but it will very slow to write file of size 1 GB

Comment: plz see my question after edit , i have attached a piece of code that im working on

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the NTFS file system (most Windows deployments are) and you don't mind doing p/invoke methods, then there is a way, way faster way of deleting chunks from a file.  You can make the file **sparse**.  With sparse files, you can eliminate a large chunk of the file with a single call.

When you do this, the file is not rewritten.  Instead, NTFS updates metadata about the extents of zeroed-out data.  The beauty of sparse files is that consumers of your file don't have to be aware of the file's sparseness.  That is, when you read from a FileStream over a sparse file, zeroed-out extents are transparently skipped.

NTFS uses such files for its own bookkeeping.  The USN journal, for example, is a very large sparse memory-mapped file.

The way you make a file sparse and zero-out sections of that file is to use the DeviceIOControl windows API.  It is arcane and requires p/invoke but if you go this route, you'll surely hide the uggles behind nice pretty function calls.

There are some issues to be aware of.  For example, if the file is moved to a non-ntfs volume and then back, the sparseness of the file can disappear - so you should program defensively.

Also, a sparse file can appear to be larger than it really is - complicating tasks involving disk provisioning.  A 5g sparse file that has been completely zeroed out still counts 5g towards a user's disk quota.

If a sparse file accumulates a lot of holes, you might want to occasionally rewrite the file in a maintenance window.  I haven't seen any real performance troubles occur, but I can at least imagine that the metadata for a swiss-cheesy sparse file might accrue some performance degradation.

Here's a link to some [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365566(v=vs.85).aspx) if you're into the idea.